# JSON schema does not validate against valid data (validictory)

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

The following data + JSON schema (generated from using JSON Schema Generator with the same data) is supposed to validate correctly. However instead I receive a valdation error here.

The validation is based on the validictory module.

```
import json
import validictory
import jsonschema

data = [{u'text': 
         u'<h1>The quick brown fox</h1>', 
         u'title': u'hello world', 
         u'location': u'Berlin', 
         u'created': u'2013-03-12T12:13:14'}]

schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
    "required": False,
    "type": "object" ,
    "properties": {
        "0" : {
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/0",
            "required": False,
            "type": "object" ,
            "properties": {
                "created" : {
                    "id": "http://jsonschema.net/0/created",
                    "required": False,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "location" : {
                    "id": "http://jsonschema.net/0/location",
                    "required": False,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "text" : {
                    "id": "http://jsonschema.net/0/text",
                    "required": False,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "title" : {
                    "id": "http://jsonschema.net/0/title",
                    "required": False,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
print validictory.validate(data,schema)

validictory.validator.FieldValidationError: Value [{u'text': u'<h1>The quick brown fox</h1>', u'created': u'2013-03-12T12:13:14', u'location': u'Berlin', u'title': u'hello world'}] for field '_data' is not of type object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation error tells you what the problem is...

It says `Value [{u'text': u'<h1>The quick brown fox</h1>', u'created': u'2013-03-12T12:13:14', u'location': u'Berlin', u'title': u'hello world'}] for field '_data' is not of type object`,
which it isn't, it's a `list`. You need to validate its contents `i.e. data[0]`, not the whole list.

Also, it looks like you generated this schema before jsonschema.net fixed how they use `id`, which was incorrect under the spec, so you probably want to remove those`id` properties.

Comment: As I wrote: the schema has been auto-generated using the _same_ data